If $f'(x) = 0$ at exactly one point, is $f(x)$ constant at exactly one point?

I have learnt that the derivative of a function is not defined at a point, but over an infinitesimally small interval $dx.$ The derivative of $f(x)$ is taken to be constant over this infinitesimally small interval, and is accepted to be $f'(x)$ at that point. So, am I right in saying that the function $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2$ is not constant at exactly one point (at $C),$ but is constant over a very small interval? But its derivative (in blue) is zero at exactly one point $(x=0$ or $-4/3),$ not over an infinitesimally small interval.
$f(x)$ has an inflection point at $A$. Does this mean that $f(x)$ is linear (no curvature) at exactly one point, or over an infinitesimally small interval? It does not make sense that $f(x)$ is linear at exactly a point. It has to be over an internal, no matter how small. Yet its second derivative (in green) at its inflection point is zero at exactly one point, not over an interval.

Technically, $dx$ is not an interval. $f$ does need to be defined on an interval, but we don't call the interval $dx.$

This function is never constant over any interval, no matter how small.  However, where $f'(x) = 0$, it will be "close to constant" in the sense that $(f(x) - f(y)) / (x-y) \to 0$ as $y \to x$. In other words, if you zoom in very close to the point where $f'(x) = 0$, it will appear close to a horizontal line, but will never actually be one.


I have learnt that the derivative of a function is not defined at a point, but over an infinitesimally small interval $dx.$

No. Let $f$ be a differentiable function. Then it is absolutely meaningful to talk about $f$'s derivative at a point (and consequently, over an interval). What is true is that $f$'s derivative at $c$ is defined with reference to punctured neighbourhoods of $c,$ in terms of how much $f$ changes over an arbitrarily small (rather than "infinitely/infinitesimally small") such neighbourhood. (In contrast, over an infinitesimally small neighbourhood, $f$'s change is correspondingly infinitesimally small.)

The derivative of $f(x)$ is taken to be constant over this infinitesimally small interval

Not at all: $f'(x)$ can absolutely be continually changing. The slope of $f$ is not generally constant over any interval, however small.

So, am I right in saying that the function $f(x) = x^3 + 2x^2$ is not constant at exactly one point (at $C),$ but is constant over a very small interval?

What does it even mean for a value to be "constant at exactly one point"? Constancy is meaningful only with reference to multiple points, otherwise we'd be saying, "at every point, $x$ is constant at exactly one point"!
Besides, why should $f$ having a constant derivative imply that $f$ has a constant value? (This is clearly false.)
Or are you now making a new point, and trying to say that $f'(c)=0$ implies that $f(x)$ has a constant value over some small interval around $c$ ? This is false too. Neither the function $x^3 + 2x^2$ nor its derivative is constant at any point. As a matter of fact, the function $x^3$ is continually increasing and never constant around the point $0.$

$f(x)$ has an inflection point at $A$. Does this mean that $f(x)$ is linear (no curvature) at exactly one point, or over an infinitesimally small interval? It does not make sense that $f(x)$ is linear at exactly a point. It has to be over an internal, no matter how small. Yet its second derivative (in green) at its inflection point is zero at exactly one point, not over an interval.

No: being approximately linear means that (for our needs) we've judged that its higher derivatives can be neglected, not that it is linear over some infinitesimally small interval.
P.S.

But its derivative (in blue) is zero at exactly one point $(x=0$ or $-4/3),$

More accurate to the facts: $f$'s derivative (in blue) is zero at at least two points: $0$ and $-4/3.$
More accurate to your intended meaning: in some interval around each stationary point of $f,$ the derivative (in blue) is zero at exactly one point.

thanks a lot for explaining and clearing up each point. I was unwell so I am a bit late. I think I understand most of what you are saying. You are basically saying that $f'(x)$ is not exactly zero at $x=-4/3$? Because graph of $f(x)$ is not exactly a flat (horizontal) line at $x=-4/3$? We can verify it by taking its derivative using first principle. We get ${3x^2+4x+3hx+2h+h^2}$ where $h—>0$? We ignore the terms containing $h$, as they are very very close to zero. But still they are not zero. So the derivative is not exactly zero, just very very close to it. This is what you mean,right?

which in turn means $f(x)$ at inflection point is not exactly linear, but approximately linear. Or it is not a perfectly flat line with negative slope, it is approximately flat with a negative slope? Again, this means $f'(x)$ at point of inflection is not exactly zero, just very close to it? Is my understanding correct?

@4d_ "You are basically saying that f′(x) is not exactly zero at x=−4/3?" Where did I suggest such a thing? In fact, I made the exact opposite assertion in the second sentence from the last.

If $f'(x)$ is exactly zero at $x=-4/3$, doesn't $f(x)$ become a perfectly line at that point? You said the function is never constant at any point or over any interval?

@4d_ 1. BTW, since a curve/line being "flat" conventionally means it has zero gradient, maybe don't call a line "flat" when you just mean that it's straight. $\quad$ 2. Why should a horizontal tangent imply a straight line at that point? A circle has two horizontal tangents yet is nowhere straight. $\quad$ 3. Your last sentence: are you now saying that a straight-line function necessarily has a constant value? $\quad$ 4. "You said the function is never constant at any point" Again: what does it even mean for a value to be constant at one point?

@4d_ $\quad$ 5. Are you perhaps conflating a curve and its tangent and its linear/quadratic/etc. approximations? $\quad$ 6. Ultimately, I think it's most helpful that you just go back to the basics: as you re-read this topic (whether your textbook or these answers), do so slowly and extremely literally (to a fault), following the text's reasoning step by step, and avoiding tacitly making any unjustified assumptions or projecting anything onto the text.


I have learnt that the derivative of a function is not defined at a
point, but over an infinitesimally small interval $dx$.

Then you have learnt wrong.
Take a real, nowhere continuous, bounded function. For example, the Dirichlet function:
$$1_\mathbb Q(x) = \begin{cases}
1&\text{for }x\in\mathbb Q\\
0&\text{for }x\notin\mathbb Q
\end{cases}$$
It is discontinuous everywhere: both $\mathbb Q$ and its complement are dense in $\mathbb R$, so the function assumes both values in each open interval, hence it has no limit anywhere.
But if you multiply it by its argument, its values get squeezed towards zero around $x=0$. As a result, the new function
$$f: x\mapsto x\cdot1_\mathbb Q(x)$$
gets a limit at $x=0$ and it is continuous just at that one point:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0 = f(0)$$
Furthermore, if you multiply that by $x$ once again, so you get
$$g: x\mapsto x^2\cdot1_\mathbb Q(x)$$
the values become squeezed even more in the neghborhood of $x=0$.
As a result, $g$ is not only continuous at $x=0$, but also differentiable – just at that single point:
$$g': \mathbb R \ni 0 = x \mapsto 0 \in\mathbb R$$
Some relevant Wikipedia articles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function


You're right, the definitions of constancy or linearity only make sense for intervals, not individual points. When we say $f'(x_0)=0$ what we really mean is that the tangent to the curve at $x=x_0$ is horizontal.
Recall the definition of the derivative as a limit:
$$f'(x_0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$
The next part will make more sense to you if you are familiar with the epsilon-delta definition of limits. But essentially what $f'(x_0)=0$ means is that you can make the difference between $f(x_0+h)$ and $f(x_0)$ arbitrarily small if you just choose a small enough value of $h$. The same holds for $f'(x_0)=c$, that is $f''(x_0)=0$.
To answer your question, yes, $f(x)$ is constant or linear over an interval, not a point. However, we only know this to be true for an infinitesimally small interval centered on the critical point or point of inflection.
Note that these aren't mathematically rigorous notions, but are still a good way to understand derivatives intuitively.

'... what we really mean is that the tangent to the curve at x=x0
is horizontal. Well, not necessarily. This holds only if the function is differentiable on an interval. For pathological functions differentiable at separate points we have no tangent.

@CiaPan You're right, but the functions OP has used as examples in his question aren't pathological.
